# Why my stream calling cannot be chained

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a function:

```
private HashMap<String,String> getProperties(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Stream<Map.Entry<String,String>> s = request.getParameterMap().entrySet().stream();
    return s.collect(HashMap::new, (map, e)->map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()), HashMap::putAll);
}
```

It works fine, but at the beginning I once tried to chained it together as most Java 8 programmers do:

```
private HashMap<String,String> getProperties(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getParameterMap().entrySet().stream().collect(HashMap::new, (map, e)->map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()), HashMap::putAll);
}
```

**There was compilation errors, could anyone explain this? and is there any workaround to chain all the calls?**

Comment: “There was compilation errors”. And surely “there are solutions”.

Comment: I don't think that your first one works fine either... `getParameterMap` returns `Map<String, String[]>`

Comment: @Eugene thanks for your comment :) my mistake

Comment: so what do you want in the end to achieve? a `Map<String, String[]>` or a `Map<String, String>`, if the second how would you map multiple `String` values that are coming from an array?

Comment: besides if you simply want to guarantee a mutable map a `HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>(); map.putAll(request.getParameterMap())` would be enough

Comment: Why do you need to do that? request.getParameterMap() is already return a map for you

Comment: @Eugene or even shorter, `new HashMap<>(request.getParameterMap())`…

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn because that is no guarantee to be a *mutable* map,but even if it were, do you want to have the option to remove some parameter? I doubt it

Comment: return map like @Holger said

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I don't want to do that either, but the returned hashMap is going to be used in another method, which takes only HashMap as a parameter :)

Comment: @Eugene as u mentioned, request.getparameterMap() returns a map, whose value is array, that is not what i need :)

Comment: Incase one parameter has multiple values, what will you do? Ex: id = [1, 2], you can not simply put it to HashMap with key = "id" because there's only one associate value will be stored in map.

Comment: and thus the question.. how *exactly* do you want it? care to provide an example?

Comment: @Eugene as u mentioned, the request.getParameterMap() returns a HashMap<String,String[]), but I am sure that in our request parameters, the key and value is one-to-one, so I have to convert the HashMap returned by request.getParameterMap() to a HashMap<String,String> so that the return HashMap can be used in another method call

Comment: So that's ez then, I will post answer

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn please :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: theoretically, 1) do you want a concrete implementation of a `Map` as a return type, for example `HashMap` 2) may be throw an Exception in case the array has more then a single entry? Or may be take the first/last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Assume only one-to-one mapping).

But I recommend you to use Map<> as return type.

```
private HashMap<String,String> getProperties(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getParameterMap().entrySet().stream()
                 .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null && e.getValue().length > 0)
                 .map(e -> new SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue()[0])) // This is part where you are sure that only one-to-one parameter value
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> v2, HashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: why put them into `SimpleEntry` via `map` and not collect them directly?

Comment: I am not sure if the String[] part can be null or empty

Comment: @Eugene glad to hear

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn glad to hear what? I don't get it. You probably targeted the wrong person in your comment

Comment: Glad it helps. English is not my native one. Sorry :)

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn where to get the SimpleEntry<>? SimpleEntry<> is not part of Java SE

Comment: It's in java.util package. Under Abstract Map class.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Thanks so much, your solution is compact (Y) and you gave the answer at first to be right

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I'll repeat that again, you don't need an extra mapping to `SimpleEntry` *again*, since you already have a `Stream<Entry>`, so no need for that `map` *at all*

Comment: Are you sure that the `getParameterMap()` does not return empty or null array? Give me a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want (in case you want a `Map` as return type), but this assumes that that array of values will have a single value

```
 private static HashMap<String, String> getProperties(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getParameterMap()
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Entry::getKey,
                    e -> e.getValue()[0],
                    (left, right) -> {
                        throw new AssertionError("more than two entries in the array");
                    },
                    HashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: I need a mutable HashMap to return